# AVQueuePlayer playback without gap and freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avqueueplayer

I use `AVQueuePlayer` to play a sequence of movies which are loaded from URLs.
I tried to initialize player instance with array of all `AVPlayerItems` that I need to play.

```
player = [[AVQueuePlayer queuePlayerWithItems:playerItemsArray]
```

But in this case `AVQueuePlayer` loads some initial part of each `AVPlayerItem` before starting playback. It causes frustrating freeze and application doesn't respond for some seconds.

There is possibility to add only first `AVPLayerItem` to player's queue, observe its state and add second item in queue only when first will reach end, but in this case there will be a gap between playback of two items caused by initializing and buffering of second `AVPlayerItem`.

Is there any way to organize gapless playback of several videos without a freeze?
Should I use some other player for this purposes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is found.

When adding new `AVPlayerItem` in queue of `AVQueuePlayer` player will synchronously wait till initial part of player item will be buffered.

So in this case player item should be buffered asynchronously and after that it can be added in the queue.
 It can be done using `[AVURLAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys: completionHandler:]`

For example:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"playable"];

[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset] autorelease];         
        [player insertItem:playerItem afterItem:nil]; 
    });

}];
```

Using this solution queue of AVQueuePlayer can be populated with items without any gaps and freezes.

Comment: Hi yury.ku, We have a same issue what you have posted. We created a sample app to test this. We add new player item once it is loaded in the didEndPlay: notification API. But still we are facing some UI freeze issue. Can you please provide more info on how did you solve this problem?

Comment: This solution doesnt work me as well, there is still a narrow gap between audiotracks

Comment: As per [AVFoundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW3):`Try to initialize an AVURLAsset using the URL, then load its tracks key.
If the tracks load successfully, then you create a player item for the asset.
`. So, you should use `NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"tracks"];` instead.

Comment: I can't tell a difference when I remove `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ { ... });`. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: This "works" but doesn't take into account the possibility that some assets may load faster than others and thus the order in which they are inserted is not guaranteed. How to maintain playback order?

Answer (score 2):

in Swift 2, working here:

```
func load() {
     let player = AVQueuePlayer()
     for url in urls {
        makeItem(url)
    }
}

func makeItem(url: String) {
    let avAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

    avAsset.loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys(["playable", "tracks", "duration"], completionHandler: {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.enqueue(avAsset: avAsset)
        })
    })
}

func enqueue(avAsset: AVURLAsset) {
    let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
    self.player.insertItem(item, afterItem: nil)
}
```

Comment: This "works" but doesn't take into account the possibility that some assets may load faster than others and thus the order in which they are inserted is not guaranteed. If playback order is not a concern this works great!

Comment: @user1171911 I have run into same problem. Can u suggest a solution to maintain playback order? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution.

```
- (void)_makePlayer{
     _player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:[SSMoviePreviewItemMaker generateAVMovieItem]]];
}

+ (AVAsset *)generateAVMovieItem{
    NSArray * array = [SSMovieFileManager getAllMovieResourceURL];
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:array[i] options:nil];
        [composition insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, asset.duration)
                             ofAsset:asset
                              atTime:composition.duration error:nil];

    }
   return composition;
}
```