# AVQueuePlayer gapless playback

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avqueueplayer, avplayeritem

I am trying to dynamically add .aac chunks (usually 10 seconds) during the playback to `AVQueuePlayer` to mimic the `AVPlayer` hls playback.

However it plays songs one after another as I wished, there is about 200ms to 400 ms gap between songs.

following question seems to have the answer it to this question but it doesn't work for me.

[AVQueuePlayer playback without gap and freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941461/avqueueplayer-playback-without-gap-and-freeze/15202471#15202471)

I have a singleton player and a singleton `avplayeritem` to keep track of the last item. 
then with following code I can successfully play the songs with gap.

```
 NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    //NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    GlobalPlayer *singleton=[GlobalPlayer sharedManager];
    //AVPlayerItem *item=[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"playable"];

    if (singleton.lastItem==nil) {
        //initilize player
        //NSArray *playerArray=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:item, nil];
        //singleton.globPlayer=[[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:playerArray];
        //[singleton.globPlayer play];

        singleton.globPlayer=[[AVQueuePlayer alloc] init];
        singleton.lastItem=[AVPlayerItem alloc];

        __block AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
        [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^()
         {
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                            {
                                playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
                                [singleton.globPlayer insertItem:playerItem afterItem:nil];
                                singleton.lastItem=playerItem;
                                [singleton.globPlayer play];
                            });

         }];

    }
    else
    {
        //[singleton.globPlayer insertItem:item afterItem:singleton.lastItem];
        __block AVPlayerItem *playerItem;
        [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^()
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
                           {
                               playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
                               [singleton.globPlayer insertItem:playerItem afterItem:singleton.lastItem];
                                singleton.lastItem=playerItem;
                           });

        }];

    }
```

Do I have to decode the chunks then feed the PCM to `AVQueuePlayer`? If that is the only solution how do I feed NSData that holds pcm to the `AVPlayerItem` ?

Comment: @matt I wouldn't be asking the question if it was working, would I? There must be something; because AVPlayer can play this hls stream url `http://playlists.ihrhls.com/c5/1469/playlist.m3u8` without any problem there are no gaps between .aac chunks. So I manually parse this hls stream and add the .acc chunks to `AVQueuePlayer` but then there is a gap in between chunks. My first guess was it was because  the way it decodes the chunks or  the way chunks are encoded problem but I am not sure.

Comment: Did you try to feed PCM files directly to player? If you think decoding is the problem decode the files first then send them to the queue , of course if you don't mind the hassle