# How does Snapchat & Instagram Stories handle skipping back and forth between clips?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, avqueueplayer, avkit

As the title states, what is used to allow for the videos to seamlessly skip both back and forwards?

I've attempted using AVPlayer with an Array of AVPlayerItems and manually swapping the current video, and I've used AVQueuePlayer and rebuilding the queue when skipping to previous video. Both implementations are still nowhere near as smooth as both of these platforms.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do the answers on this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14941461/avqueueplayer-playback-without-gap-and-freeze